# Why is my upper table not obeying the css width rule?

Tags: html, css, width

I have a simple set of two tables I am wanting to line up, but for some reason the upper one, while having the same rules as the second one doesn't want to obey the width rule.

Here is the HTML:

```
<body>
    <div>
        <div class="clientSearchWrapper">
            <table class="clientSearchTableHeader">
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="6">Client Search</td>
                    <td colspan="2"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="clientNumber"><input type="text" /></td>
                    <td class="clientName"><input type="text" /></td>
                    <td class="clientAddress"><input type="text" /></td>
                    <td class="clientCity"><input type="text" /></td>
                    <td class="clientState"><input type="text" /></td>
                    <td class="clientZip"><input type="text" /></td>
                    <td class="clientMarket"><input type="text" /></td>
                    <td class="clientActive"><input type="text" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <div class="clientInfoWrapper">
                <table class="clientSearchTable">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="clientNumber">ClientNumber</td>
                        <td class="clientName">CompanyName</td>
                        <td class="clientAddress">CompanyAddress</td>
                        <td class="clientCity">CompanyCity</td>
                        <td class="clientState">CompanyState</td>
                        <td class="clientZip">CompanyZip</td>
                        <td class="clientMarket">Market</td>
                        <td class="clientActive">ClientActive</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="clientNumber">ClientNumber</td>
                        <td class="clientName">CompanyName</td>
                        <td class="clientAddress">CompanyAddress</td>
                        <td class="clientCity">CompanyCity</td>
                        <td class="clientState">CompanyState</td>
                        <td class="clientZip">CompanyZip</td>
                        <td class="clientMarket">Market</td>
                        <td class="clientActive">ClientActive</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="clientNumber">ClientNumber</td>
                        <td class="clientName">CompanyName</td>
                        <td class="clientAddress">CompanyAddress</td>
                        <td class="clientCity">CompanyCity</td>
                        <td class="clientState">CompanyState</td>
                        <td class="clientZip">CompanyZip</td>
                        <td class="clientMarket">Market</td>
                        <td class="clientActive">ClientActive</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="clientNumber">ClientNumber</td>
                        <td class="clientName">CompanyName</td>
                        <td class="clientAddress">CompanyAddress</td>
                        <td class="clientCity">CompanyCity</td>
                        <td class="clientState">CompanyState</td>
                        <td class="clientZip">CompanyZip</td>
                        <td class="clientMarket">Market</td>
                        <td class="clientActive">ClientActive</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="clientNumber">ClientNumber</td>
                        <td class="clientName">CompanyName</td>
                        <td class="clientAddress">CompanyAddress</td>
                        <td class="clientCity">CompanyCity</td>
                        <td class="clientState">CompanyState</td>
                        <td class="clientZip">CompanyZip</td>
                        <td class="clientMarket">Market</td>
                        <td class="clientActive">ClientActive</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="clientNumber">ClientNumber</td>
                        <td class="clientName">CompanyName</td>
                        <td class="clientAddress">CompanyAddress</td>
                        <td class="clientCity">CompanyCity</td>
                        <td class="clientState">CompanyState</td>
                        <td class="clientZip">CompanyZip</td>
                        <td class="clientMarket">Market</td>
                        <td class="clientActive">ClientActive</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="clientNumber">ClientNumber</td>
                        <td class="clientName">CompanyName</td>
                        <td class="clientAddress">CompanyAddress</td>
                        <td class="clientCity">CompanyCity</td>
                        <td class="clientState">CompanyState</td>
                        <td class="clientZip">CompanyZip</td>
                        <td class="clientMarket">Market</td>
                        <td class="clientActive">ClientActive</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="clientNumber">ClientNumber</td>
                        <td class="clientName">CompanyName</td>
                        <td class="clientAddress">CompanyAddress</td>
                        <td class="clientCity">CompanyCity</td>
                        <td class="clientState">CompanyState</td>
                        <td class="clientZip">CompanyZip</td>
                        <td class="clientMarket">Market</td>
                        <td class="clientActive">ClientActive</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="clientNumber">ClientNumber</td>
                        <td class="clientName">CompanyName</td>
                        <td class="clientAddress">CompanyAddress</td>
                        <td class="clientCity">CompanyCity</td>
                        <td class="clientState">CompanyState</td>
                        <td class="clientZip">CompanyZip</td>
                        <td class="clientMarket">Market</td>
                        <td class="clientActive">ClientActive</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="clientNumber">ClientNumber</td>
                        <td class="clientName">CompanyName</td>
                        <td class="clientAddress">CompanyAddress</td>
                        <td class="clientCity">CompanyCity</td>
                        <td class="clientState">CompanyState</td>
                        <td class="clientZip">CompanyZip</td>
                        <td class="clientMarket">Market</td>
                        <td class="clientActive">ClientActive</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="clientNumber">ClientNumber</td>
                        <td class="clientName">CompanyName</td>
                        <td class="clientAddress">CompanyAddress</td>
                        <td class="clientCity">CompanyCity</td>
                        <td class="clientState">CompanyState</td>
                        <td class="clientZip">CompanyZip</td>
                        <td class="clientMarket">Market</td>
                        <td class="clientActive">ClientActive</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="clientNumber">ClientNumber</td>
                        <td class="clientName">CompanyName</td>
                        <td class="clientAddress">CompanyAddress</td>
                        <td class="clientCity">CompanyCity</td>
                        <td class="clientState">CompanyState</td>
                        <td class="clientZip">CompanyZip</td>
                        <td class="clientMarket">Market</td>
                        <td class="clientActive">ClientActive</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="clientNumber">ClientNumber</td>
                        <td class="clientName">CompanyName</td>
                        <td class="clientAddress">CompanyAddress</td>
                        <td class="clientCity">CompanyCity</td>
                        <td class="clientState">CompanyState</td>
                        <td class="clientZip">CompanyZip</td>
                        <td class="clientMarket">Market</td>
                        <td class="clientActive">ClientActive</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="clientNumber">ClientNumber</td>
                        <td class="clientName">CompanyName</td>
                        <td class="clientAddress">CompanyAddress</td>
                        <td class="clientCity">CompanyCity</td>
                        <td class="clientState">CompanyState</td>
                        <td class="clientZip">CompanyZip</td>
                        <td class="clientMarket">Market</td>
                        <td class="clientActive">ClientActive</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="clientNumber">ClientNumber</td>
                        <td class="clientName">CompanyName</td>
                        <td class="clientAddress">CompanyAddress</td>
                        <td class="clientCity">CompanyCity</td>
                        <td class="clientState">CompanyState</td>
                        <td class="clientZip">CompanyZip</td>
                        <td class="clientMarket">Market</td>
                        <td class="clientActive">ClientActive</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="clientNumber">ClientNumber</td>
                        <td class="clientName">CompanyName</td>
                        <td class="clientAddress">CompanyAddress</td>
                        <td class="clientCity">CompanyCity</td>
                        <td class="clientState">CompanyState</td>
                        <td class="clientZip">CompanyZip</td>
                        <td class="clientMarket">Market</td>
                        <td class="clientActive">ClientActive</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

And here is the CSS:

```
body
{
    background-color: #fff;

    width: 1200px;

    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;

    position:absolute; 
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    z-index:-1;
}

.clientSearchWrapper
{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
}

.clientSearchTableHeader
{
    width: 100%; /*Have also tried to set width to 1200px, just like in the body*/
    margin: auto;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

.clientInfoWrapper
{
    height: 200px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    border: 2px inset #888;
}

.clientSearchTable
{
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

.clientSearchTable td
{
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
}

.clientSearchTable td.titleBar
{

}

.clientSearchTable td.recordCount
{

}

.clientSearchTable td.clientNumber
{
    border-right: 1px solid #000;
    text-align: center;
}

.clientSearchTable td.clientName
{
    border-right: 1px solid #000;
}

.clientSearchTable td.clientAddress
{
    border-right: 1px solid #000;
}

.clientSearchTable td.clientCity
{
    border-right: 1px solid #000;
}

.clientSearchTable td.clientState
{
    border-right: 1px solid #000;
    text-align: center;
}

.clientSearchTable td.clientZip
{
    border-right: 1px solid #000;
}

.clientSearchTable td.clientMarket
{
    border-right: 1px solid #000;
    text-align: center;
}

.clientSearchTable td.clientActive
{

}
```

As you can see, in the `<table class="clientSearchTableHeader">` element, using the css rule `width`, I am explicitly telling it to set the width to 100% (just as I did in the `<table class="clientSearchTable">` element and its parent, the `<div class=clientInfoWrapper">` element. I've tried specifying with pixels (1200px) and even adding `!important` to the css rule (not that it has anything else overruling it anyway). The `<table class="clientSearchTableHeader">` element insists on setting itself to 1400 pixels (a greater width than even the `<body>` element by 200 pixels. I'm sure I could explicitly tell the `<td>`'s to have set widths, or the `<input>` elements, or both, but I want to keep this more dynamic, if possible, plus, I didn't have to with the lower table (`<table class="clientSearchTable">`). Just wondering what's going on here and why the width rule in the css for the table with the class "clientSearchTable" is being ignored.

What am I doing wrong?

Here is the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1fhtk4sw/4/

Comment: what is your requirement?

Comment: I see 1200px width for all table. But is not better the first table are the thead, with 2 row, and the second are the tbody?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your css. Your input fields defaults to width set by the browser. It is pushing the table content beyond 1200px.

> .clientSearchTableHeader input {
>      width: 100%;
>   }

Comment: Okay, awesome, thank you!

I know I could have fixed the width of everything, but I really wanted to know what was going on here for my own personal education, and thanks to you, I have!

Comment: Good. Happy to hear it worked. You have to be careful with the bottom table. If any cell's content is too big to fit, it will push the columns. If you want them to align properly all the time, its better to have only one table and use CSS adjust the look.

Comment: Well, couldn't I just set the text-overflow to hidden?

Comment: Yes. If your okay with part of the content not displayed if it goes over.

Comment: Yeah, it just so happens that's what I'm going for there. I may set these particular fields static, I'm not sure.